# Sudden errors with as.data.frame with previously used code and objects

Tags: r

To analyze data for the past 2 years, I have used as.data.frame to generate a sample table and have had no issues whatsoever (including just last month):

```
sampleName <- c("cKO1", "cKO2", "cKO3", "WT1", "WT2", "WT3")

fileName <- c("cKO1_counts.txt", "cKO2_counts.txt", "cKO3_counts.txt", "WT1_counts.txt", "WT2_counts.txt", "WT3_counts.txt")

condition <- c("cKO", "cKO", "cKO", "WT", "WT", "WT")

sampleTable <- as.data.frame(sampleName, fileName, condition, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Resulting data frame: [image: SampleTable]

However, now if I try to do the exact same thing, I get the following error: [image: Error]

Again, I have not changed anything since the last time I analyzed data over a month ago. I was using the previous version of R (3.5.0) last month when it worked however, I got this error using the previous version and also after updating to the latest version. I have also tried making new lists in a new RStudio session and I get the same error.

There are two problems from what I can see, and I'm not sure how to overcome them. I'm also not sure why they suddenly are causing errors:

(1) using as.data.frame to make a data frame from more than 2 objects gives the error with !optional

(2) using as.data.frame is assigning the last object in the command to become the row names, which is causing an error with the "condition" list that doesn't occur with the other lists

Examples: [image: Troubleshooting]

Comment: Please paste as plain text, not images.

Comment: You don't need `as.data.frame`. Simply `data.frame` works.

Comment: @yarnabrina is correct.
For future reference, here's whats happening in your error: `as.data.frame` has some default parameters. Since you have not specifically named the parameters in you call of `as.data.frame`, it is trying to apply them, in order, to the default parameter. Your error comes from you assignment of `condition`, which it thinks is `optional = condition`. Since `optional` can only take a boolean, you get an error because `condition` is not a boolean.

Comment: Thank you @yarnabrina, this indeed solved the issue!

Comment: And thank you @David for the explanation!